# I have been studying piano from age 6 to 15 or I have studied piano from age 6 to 15

Tags: past-tense

Which sentence is correct?

> I have been studying piano from age 6 to 15
>   I have studied piano
>   from age 6 to 15.

Answer (score 3):

Neither of your sentences agrees with the tag "*past-tense*" and neither of them is correct.

You should use the Past Simple here:

- I studied piano from age 6 to 15.

Comment: Although both sentences could be fine if the speaker was 15.

Comment: @J.R. Wouldn't that be odd?

Comment: Sure, but I think it’s important to talk about exceptions when saying something is “incorrect”.

Answer (score 1):

In your examples

> I have been studying...

means you are still studying, whereas

> I have studied piano from age 6 to 15.

may mean you want to say you studied for a while but no longer, better might be

> I studied piano from age 6 to 15.
>   I took piano (lessons) from age 6 to 15.

Comment: As J.R. said, "Although both sentences could be fine if the speaker was 15."